# Is there a way to get icons on the tabs in conemu?

Tags: conemu

Is there a way to get icons on the tabs in conemu? I would like the tab to have a PowerShell icon for my PowerShell tab for example. I have got it to work for the taskbar/jump list by specifying a task parameter, but I haven't figured out how to get icon on the tabs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tab icons are available from the box for most of shells (if shell executable has icon in its resource).

If your shell does not have icon, or you want to use custom icon, look below for examples:

- use `/icon "C:\cygwin\Cygwin.ico"` in your task parameters
- use `-new_console:C:"C:\cygwin\Cygwin.ico"` in the shell arguments

Comment: This would be a great feature.

Comment: Maybe @Maximus could know :) Task parameter `/icon "C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"` doesn't work for me. I have to use command parameter `-cur_console:C:"C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"`. I'm using ConEmu 140416 64 bit.

Comment: "/icon ..." is working on my side. You know how to report bugs...

Comment: What does the `:C:` part means in `-new_console:C:"C:\cygwin...`?

Comment: All switches are explained in docs: https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the Settings menu, specify the following in the Task parameters:

```
/icon "C:\PathToYour\TaskIcon.ico"
```

[image: ConEmu Settings]

Comment: This does not work for me (ConEmu 140416 64bit). Should it work? I have to use `-cur_console:C:"C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"` as command parameter instead. Task parameter `/icon "C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"` does nothing.

Comment: The Task parameters value of `/icon "C:\cygwin\Cygwin.ico"` works for me, although the "Run as Administrator" shield is overlayed above it to the point where it's difficult to see.

Comment: You can create a bug report on [ConEmu's Google Code project page](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/entry).